# flutter lists and provider how to increase an int value in the list?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm using a Listview.builder to build a list of buttons based on information from a list which is housed in a change notifier.
here is an example of the items contained in the list:

```
ListItem(cost1: 2, cost2: 0, canSelect: 1, timesChosen: 0, name: 'Item 1'),
```

and here is an example of the object (button) that is being built in the listview.builder:

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        context.read<MyProvider>().MyList[index].timesChosen++;
                      },
                      child: EquipmentButton(
                          text: context.read<MyProvider>().MyList[index].name,
                          Cost1: '${context.read<MyProvider>().MyList[index].cost1}',
                          timesChosen: '${context.read<MyProvider>().MyList[index].timesChosen}',
                     ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: context.read<MyProvider>().MyList.length),
```

when I run this code, It builds the buttons correctly. but when a button is pressed, I get the below error:
Class 'ListItem' has no instance setter 'timesChosen='.
Receiver: Instance of 'ListItem'
Tried calling: timesChosen=1

How do i get it to increase the value of timesChosen in the list?

thanks so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. just had to add a void function in the Listitem class.

```html
class EquipmentAndCosts {
  int cost1;
  int cost2;
  int canSelect;
  int timesChosen;
  String name;

  void timesChosenIncrease() {
    timesChosen++;
  }

  EquipmentAndCosts(
      {required this.name,
      required this.cost1,
      required this.cost2,
      required this.canSelect,
      required this.timesChosen});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to update the timesChosen property of an instance of ListItem using the timesChosen++ expression, which assumes the presence of a setter for that property. For you code to work, you should ensure that the ListItem class has a setter method for the timesChosen property. Below is an example with the setter:

```
class ListItem {
  int cost1;
  int cost2;
  int canSelect;
  int _timesChosen; // hold the value of timesChosen

  String name;

  // Getter for timesChosen
  int get timesChosen => _timesChosen;

  // Setter for timesChosen
  set timesChosen(int value) {
    _timesChosen = value;
  }

  ListItem(this._timesChosen, {required this.cost1, required this.cost2, required this.canSelect, required this.name});
}
```

The above code snippet should work with the code in your listview.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the answer. putting the underscore in front of timesChosen at the the top of your example (to hold the value) is is producing the error 'timesChosen' isn't a field in the enclosing class. at this.timesChosen,

Comment: I edited the ListItem definition. This should work, note that _timesChosen is positional and not named parameter here because _ are not allowed in named parameters.